# Descobrir qual número de 1 a N está faltando em uma lista com N - 1 números

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmo

Escreva uma função que, dada uma lista com N − 1 inteiros numerados de 1 a N, descubra qual número inteiro desse intervalo está faltando.

Entrada: O parametro de entrada é uma lista L de tamanho N − 1 contendo numeros inteiros (não
repetidos) de 1 a N.

Saída: A função deve retornar o número inteiro x que pertence ao intervalo [1, N] mas que não
pertence a lista de entrada L.

Exemplos

Entrada: [3,1] ; Saída: 2
Entrada: [1,2,3,5] ; Saída: 4
Entrada: [2,4,3] ; Saída: 1

```
    def quebracabecas(lista_pecas):
        i = 1
        while i < len(lista_pecas):
            if i not in lista_pecas:
                return 
            contador += 1
        return lista_pecas
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena entender [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e ler o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score 1):

Dadas as restrições do problema e o fato de que não é preciso validar a lista (ou seja, posso confiar que os números estão entre 1 e N e a lista sempre tem N - 1 números e não há repetidos), dá pra fazer de um jeito "esperto".

A soma de todos os números entre 1 e N se dá pela fórmula da soma da PA: `N * (N + 1) / 2`.

Sendo assim, eu posso calcular a soma da PA (ou seja, de todos os números de 1 a N), e deste valor eu subtraio a soma dos elementos da lista. O resultado será o número que está faltando:

```
def quebracabecas(lista_pecas):
    n = len(lista_pecas) + 1
    somatotal = n * (n + 1) // 2
    return somatotal - sum(lista_pecas)

print(quebracabecas([3, 1])) # 2
print(quebracabecas([1, 2, 3, 5])) # 4
print(quebracabecas([2, 4, 3])) # 1
```

Como a lista tem N - 1 números, basta somar 1 ao tamanho dela para obter o N.

Depois obtenho a soma de todos os números de 1 a N, usando a fórmula já citada (só usei o operador de divisão inteira `//` para que o resultado não seja um `float`, até porque no caso da soma da PA é garantido que o resultado é inteiro então não há perigo de haver arredondamento indevido).

Depois basta subtrair a soma dos elementos da lista (obtida com `sum`).

---

Outra alternativa (menos eficiente) é ordenar a lista e depois ver qual está faltando:

```
def quebracabecas(lista_pecas):
    valores = sorted(lista_pecas)
    for i in range(len(valores)):
        if i + 1 != valores[i]:
            return i + 1 # valor não corresponde à posição, retorna
    # se percorreu todos é porque o último é o que falta
    return len(valores) + 1
```

Após ordenar a lista, basta ver se o primeiro elemento é 1, o segundo é 2, etc. O que não corresponder à posição é o que está faltando.

Answer (score -2):

Eu faria assim usaria um criaria um set com o range do seu array de entrada, e usaria ele para conferir qual item esta faltando, o big O nao é muito bom mas para resolucao do problema e para datasets pequenos acredito que esta ok

```
def quebracabecas(lista):
    teste_set = set(range(lista[0],lista[-1]))
    for i in lista:
        if i in teste_set:
            teste_set.remove(i)
        
    return teste_set
```

Comment: Vc chegou a testar com os exemplos da pergunta? Porque esse código não funciona: https://ideone.com/AyQTtE

Comment: Creio que seu range dentro do set teria que começar de 1 e antes disso você teria que ordenar sua lista. Algo assim: `lista = sorted(lista)
    teste_set = set(range(1,lista[-1]))`. Abraço!

Comment: @lmonferrari Isso ainda falha se o número faltante for o "N" - ex: se a lista for `[2, 1]`, o número que falta é o 3, mas esse código retorna um `set` vazio: https://ideone.com/AsY5JU - outro detalhe é que está sendo retornado um `set` contendo o número, em vez do próprio número.

Comment: @hkotsubo, bom dia! O que eu havia entendido sobre o problema é que deveria retornar um número dentro de um range, [2,1] na minha visão não deveria retornar nada pois bastaria ordenar. Caso tenha que retornar o 3, realmente falha. Abraço!

Comment: @lmonferrari O problema diz que tem "N - 1" números entre 1 e N. Se N for 3, ela tem 2 números entre 1 e 3 e portanto na lista `[2,1]` está faltando o 3 - do enunciado: "*A função deve retornar o número inteiro x que pertence ao intervalo [1, N] mas que não pertence a lista de entrada L*"